# (Tizen Web Wearble App) The value of RR interval is always 0

Tags: tizen

[Web application] Human Activity Monitor
I am trying to get heart rate, rr interval, and accelerometer data from gear s3.
However, the value of rr interval is always 0.
It works fine in the emulator, only on the actual device.
Does anyone solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share the binary version of your Gear S3 ?

Comment: Sorry. I do not know how to check the binary version of gear s3. Information related to gear s3 is as follows.
Model Number: SM-R770,
Tizen version: 2.3.2.1,
Software version: R770XXUIAPL2,
KNOX Version: 2.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the power plicy of tizen products. have a look at this bug report:

https://bugs.tizen.org/browse/TW-47?jql=

Comment: Thanks for the Info, really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the first time I am seeing the

"RR interval always zero"

I have implemented sample code but all I get in return is **0** in rRInterval.

[image]

You would also like to check this post on Tizen developers forum.

https://developer.tizen.org/forums/general-support/heart-rate-and-rr-interval-value-please-please-help?langswitch=en

This could be a bug I guess. Please feel free to report the issue on Tizen bug Tracker.

https://www.tizen.org/community/bug-tracker